# Scaling an SVG background

Tags: html, css, svg

I have two html elements with different sizes and I'd like to use the same svg background for both elements so that it automatically scales to the size of each.

```
.bg {
        background: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'><path d='M 20 0 L 40 14 L 32 36 L 8 36 L 1 14 z' stroke='#000' stroke-width='2px' fill='red' /></svg>")  
}

#x { 
    width:40px;
    height:40px;
    border:1px solid red;
}

#y { 
    width:120px;
    height:120px;
    border:1px solid red;
}
```

Basically, I want the y's polygon to be 100% of y's width, while keeping the same (not necessarily given) SVG for both divs.

http://jsfiddle.net/zNdLb/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you want something like this then:

```
.bg {
        background: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,%3Csvg%20xmlns%3D%27http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%27%20width%3D%22100%25%22%20height%3D%22100%25%22%20viewBox%3D%220%20-2%2042%2042%22%3E%3Cpath%20d%3D%27M%2020%200%20L%2040%2014%20L%2032%2036%20L%208%2036%20L%201%2014%20z%27%20stroke%3D%27%23000%27%20stroke-width%3D%272px%27%20fill%3D%27red%27%20%2F%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E")  
}
```

Note that what you posted was [not a valid data URI](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2396#section-2.4) and many UAs will refuse to display it as it contains invalid characters such as < and >

Unescaped the SVG looks something like this. It's the [`viewBox`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/viewBox) that makes the difference.

```
<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 -2 42 42">
    <path d='M 20 0 L 40 14 L 32 36 L 8 36 L 1 14 z' stroke='#000' stroke-width='2px' fill='red' />
</svg>
```

I used [this](http://dopiaza.org/tools/datauri/index.php) to convert it to a valid data URI